# Encryption of data payload in Chirp

Tags: security, chirp

I am working on a POC to demonstrate how we can use Chirp to power offline wallet transactions - hence need the data exchange to be extremely secure. Does chirp sdk have inbuilt encryption or it is recommended to use industry standards such as AES on top of it too in the application layer?

Answer (score 1):

Chirp does not have built in encryption, it only provides the transport layer. So as you say, it is up to the developer to integrate standards such as AES at the application layer.